# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I can't find anything to resolve this and have tried multiple things.

Task: I am trying to add bundles to an old existing web project. I have added everything I need I believe as I have done the same in a new project and it works.

```
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/bundles/masterstyle" />
```

This seems to be where the issue has started with this line above. I installed via nuget the web optimization webforms package which fixed the squiggly line under webopt. However, now, I am getting 2 issues.

1. BundleReference has a squiggly line saying "Element
   'BundleReference' is not a known element/ This can occur if there is
   a complication error in the Web site, or the web.config file is
   missing".
2. It also can't seem to find the package I have just installed which
       is "Could not load file or assembly
       'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms' or one of its
       dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified".

If anyone can help resolve this, it would be greatly appreciated. Been stuck on it for 4 hours now.

Here is the likely relevant stuff in my web.config file:

```
<pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
        <tagMapping>
            <add tagType="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm" mappedTagType="we3.Site.Form" />
        </tagMapping>
        <controls>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Install it from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms/

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms
```

Or you can manually download it from: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms/1.1.3

and add it as reference to your project (unzip first the .nupkg file)

Comment: Hi Sergui, It says 'Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms.1.1.3' already exists in project'. Also I can see the System.Web.Optimization.dll in the bin folder if that helps.

Comment: can you also see it in the References section of your project?

Comment: I can't see a references section of my project. It's a fairly old project I have taken over. I right clicked the project > add reference and I couldn't even find anything under optimization so it looks like I can't add it that way.

Comment: you should see something like this in solution explorer: https://imgur.com/a/PUq6nJm and there you should find a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms

Comment: This is all I have for this project... https://imgur.com/a/Q1gLo8W further down the solution explorer are just basically aspx pages and then the config file. The second picture on that link is it all correctly working in a seperate project I have.

Comment: It might be that your project is broken, try to create a new project and move the code and resources from the existing one to the new one. DLLs should not be placed in the bin folder. The DLLs should be placed in an anohter folder, outside of the project and just add them as references to the project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'd rather not do this as that would be a hell of a lot of code to move.

Comment: Have a look in your .vbproject file with notepad++ at the ProjectTypeGuids node. For VB web application the node should have the following value: <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>. If yours is different, try to manually update it. You can also find a list with all the project types here: https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Comment: How do I find the .vbproject file? I am looking at the project files in my local repository but I'm not sure what it would be. I have opened up the .sln file in notepad++ and it has a bunch of stuff in it but nothing with <ProjectTypeGuids>

Comment: you need to use windows explorer and navigate to the folder in which your project is located. or you could right click on the project node in visual studio and select "Open Folder in File Explorer"

Comment: I am in the folder that the project is located, I am just unsure of which file to open in notepad

Answer (score 0):

Installing the package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization is what resolved this for me.
`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`